# Shouldn't setClip function return a new file using just_audio package?

Tags: just-audio

In my app, I allow users to edit their audio recording and I use **[just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)** to do this. When the audio is clipped from 30 seconds to 20 seconds I realized that only the duration of the audio changed but the file length did not change so the audio isn't edited as intended because when the clipped audio is sent to the server, it still remains as the original unedited file. Is that how the clip feature was intended to work or I am not doing something right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just_audio is just an audio player, so it doesn't do file editing and file writing. `ClippingAudioSource` is equivalent to `ClippingMediaSource` in ExoPlayer and it is intended only for selecting a clip to play during playback, without modifying the original.